# How to get values of bind parameters from Oracle JDBC PreparedStatement object

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I want to implement logging of all executed statements with actual bind parameters when using Oracle JDBC. And I would prefer that I could create such logging method only passing PreparedStatement object as parameter.

For example I have created PreparedStatement and have bound one parameter

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(
    "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employee_id = ?");
ps.setInt(1,1);
```

Now I would like to be able to get from ps the actual SQL statement "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employe_id = 1" that I could put in log file.

So far I found that I can use

```
((oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement) ps).getOriginalSql()
```

to get

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employe_id = ?
```

Now I need some way to get the list of current bind variables from ps so that I could replace ? with bind parameter values.

I tried to look in ps.getClass().getDeclaredFields() and ps.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredFields() but so far couldn't find the place where bind parameter values and their types are stored.

Any suggestions where to look for them?

Answer (score 2):

Most logging framework have the notion for [Nested Diagnostic Context](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/NDC.html). You could save your query and its parameters there when you fill up the prepared statement.

Or, perhaps, do it in one step:

```
PreparedStatement fillAndLog(Connection conn, String query, Object... args) {
    int i = 0;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
    for (Object o : args) {
       if (o instanceof String) {
           pstmt.setString(i, (String)o);
       } // else...
       i++;
    }
    log.debug(String.format(query.replaceAll("\\?", "%s"), args));
    return pstmt;
}
```

Comment: I still need to generate it just from PreparedStatement. I need this for one library where I am adding Oracle support in addition to MySQL and PostgreSQL and other databases and there the logging function accepts just PreparedStatement object as argument.

In MySQL and PostgreSQL JDBC drivers if you call toString() on PreparedStatement object then it returns SQL with included bind parameters - I need to implement similar functionality for Oracle.

Comment: Then maybe change the library itself to work this way too? Other than that, start debugging your oracle code and break on the prepared statement. Then look at the structure and locate the private place where it stores the values.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [p6spy](http://www.p6spy.com/) , it's a proxy to your database driver that allows monitoring and logging.

Comment: As I commented on previous answer I want to implement Oracle support in one existing library and therefore need to do this logging programmatically and not using additional tool.

Comment: It can't be done with just the PreparedStatement.  If you don't see it in the javadocs API, you can't do it.