# how to print out sql query that will be sent to oracle

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

I would like to verify that the sql query I'm sending to Oracle is the one I actually want. I was wondering how do I do that? I can print out the statement before I bind the variables, ie. I get this from the console:

```
UPDATE MY_TABLE=tableName SET COL1=?, COL2=?, COL3=? WHERE PK=?
```

But I would like to see the actual statement after I have set the variables to the values.

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1130886/how-to-get-values-of-bind-parameters-from-oracle-jdbc-preparedstatement-object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [log4jdbc](http://code.google.com/p/log4jdbc/)

By using this you can also see the bind parameters etc along with the sql output.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of just utilizing what is available w/o appealing to log4jdbc?

Comment: @jdbcnewbie. No, the database itself only sees the question marks and gets the bound values later. That way, it can cache how to execute the query for optimization.

Comment: @FRotthowe: Thanks. Sad for my purposes though. :-(

Comment: Typically you can activate/utilize logging on the database server.

Comment: @FRotthowe of course you can see it on the server, just set [trace event 10046, level 12](http://www.juliandyke.com/Diagnostics/Trace/EnablingTrace.html).

Comment: @Gaius: you should have posted your comment as answer

Answer (score 0):

A better tool may be [p6spy](http://andykayley.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-print-out-bind-variables-in-java.html).